# same ffmpeg preset got way slower in X265 compared to a year ago - why?

Tags: ffmpeg, performance, speed, h.265

If I compare several ffmpeg versions, the speed got down by 50% even with the same encoding profile "medium" so I wonder what the change was. That change happend any time in summer 2021.
I wonder if i need to adjust anything because the settings / profiles might have been renamed?

actual version:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar_eIBtD4lGqh_otbJxfp2L67nV0Ow?e=uACriV

oldversion
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar_eIBtD4lGqiblDjrJh3fjiLXpaFg?e=mksNlk

4K X265 encoding speed with preset medium got down from ~7.4 FPS to 3.4 FPS on a 18core 7980 XE at 4 Ghz. 100% CPU usage is the case for both versions.

[image: see the versions here]

Edit: Noticed that my newer build (done in a ubuntu VM) does not use the cpu accerleration featured compared to the old which does the same

```
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+34-7a5709048
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 10.2.0][32 bit][noasm] 10bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: none!
x265 [warning]: Turning on repeat-headers for HDR compatibility
x265 [warning]: lowering VBV buffer size to 25000Kb
x265 [info]: Main 10 profile, Level-5 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 32 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 6 / wpp(34 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 23 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 35 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-21.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 25000 / 8000 / 0.900
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=8 deblock sao
```

```
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+11-c8905a745
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 10.2.0][64 bit] 10bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [warning]: Turning on repeat-headers for HDR compatibility
x265 [warning]: lowering VBV buffer size to 25000Kb
x265 [info]: Main 10 profile, Level-5 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 36 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 6 / wpp(34 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 23 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 35 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-21.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 25000 / 8000 / 0.900
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=8 deblock sao
```

Comment: It looks like your older version of `ffmpeg` is 64-bit while your newer one is 32-bit. The 64 bit version also looks to be using SSE and other features which can significantly speed up certain operations.

Comment: yeah already digging into it, wonder how that changed as i did not change the method in building the same and i do build x64, maybe i copy a wrong build result to my cloud